# How can I run a workflow against all items in a list at once (2007)

Tags: list, workflow

Is it possible to run a workflow on ALL items in a list at the same time in SP2007?

I have a list with a choice field...the users want to change the choices available, and update the existing items to th new values.

I can't find a way of doing this except one-at-a-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way in the end.
Not shocked at all to find there was no simple way to do this...SP never ceases to dissapoint me.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/24258/7419