# Workflow all items on a list

Tags: 2013, workflow

I need to run a workflow for an entire list to change the items permissions.
How could i do that?

I've read about the extra column and the datasheet view but i'm looking for other approach. [Datasheet view approach](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24253/easiest-way-to-start-sharepoint-workflows-on-a-bunch-of-list-items-in-sharepoint/24258#24258)

Comment: On what event the workflow should start?

Comment: @Amal No event, i need to activate the workflow manually

Comment: Workflow it will be difficult to implement. I think it would be easier if you create client side code to do this on a button click.

Comment: One note - on Client side we can't elevate code. So the logged in user should have enough permission to break permission.

Comment: Yes but for example I can add the button with a certain css class and in the page insert a Content Editor targeting the users so in it with css I can show the button only for a certain type of users