# Creating a Workflow to copy list items to a SharePoint Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am trying to copy list items in SharePoint 2013 by creating a Workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013. The SharePoint List contains the list of holidays in a year. I would like to copy this Information to a SharePoint Calendar. Kindly suggest ways to go about it.

Input

```
**Date**   **Holiday**                
25 Dec       Christmas
```

Output

In the SharePoint Calendar that event should be added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can create a simple workflow to do that following these steps:

1. Click on List Workflow on SPD and choose the Holiday list (make sure to mark workflow to start automatically when an item is create)
2. From the Action Menu, choose `Create Item in this list`
3. Click on `this list` hyperlink on that `Create Item in this list` Action
4. Choose the `Calendar` List from the Drop Down
5. Choose the field from the calendar list and the value will be coming from the Holiday list (i.e. map Title field on the calendar to Holiday field on the Holiday list
6. Save the workflow and publish it
7. Create a new Holiday and check if an item has been added to the calendar.

Note: this workflow will run on new items you add to the Holiday list, if you want to do it on existing items, there are mulitple posts regards this like this [Easiest way to start SharePoint workflows on a bunch of list items in SharePoint 2007?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24253/easiest-way-to-start-sharepoint-workflows-on-a-bunch-of-list-items-in-sharepoint)

Comment: I would like to do it for an existing list. I went through the link you had mentioned but that is for SharePoint 2007. Could you please list out the steps similarly for SharePoint 2013, for an existing list?

Comment: it is a similar concept! You will be creating a new column (call it runworkflow, for example and the default value = No) of type single line of text and make sure your workflow runs when the item is changed. The first line of the workflow logic (before the copying process), check if the runworkflow = No, if the condition is met,run the logic of the workflow and set runworkflow = Yes.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't even tried the process that Ahmed outlined, give it a go as this is a simple task to do in designer (i know, it's only simple when you know how and everybody needs to learn).  It might be worth going through a few workflow tutorials as I'd be very suprised if similar examples aren't already out there and that's how I learned a lot of the basics.